# Content Search - How to choose boost values

Tags: content-search, lucene, azure-search

I'm updating some of our search code to utilise boosting of different fields. We have been given a specification of the boosting values to be applied to different fields. We are covering 15 fields in total with boost values ranging from 24 to 50 (steps of 2). No other fields have custom boost values applied.

Is there some sort of rule of thumb on how to decide on appropriate boost values?
I experimented by changing one boost value from 50 to 100 and seemed to get *better results* this way (ie an expected page appeared first in the results).